# unrecognized selector for calling a function from NSTimer in my Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

How should I declare a function in swift so that I can use NSTimer.  I'm currently getting the error :

`'-[MyClass.MyViewController displayOfflineTimerMessage]: unrecognized selector`

I tried adding @objc and dynamic in front of my function but neither worked.

```
   func sendOfflineSystemMessageIfNeccesary(username:String) {

        var debounceTimer = offlineNotificationDebounceList["username"];
        if let timer = debounceTimer {
            //todo: log warning message since we should never get here
            timer.invalidate()
        }

        debounceTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: debounceTimeInSeconds, target: self, selector: Selector("displayOfflineTimerMessage"), userInfo: username, repeats: false)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(debounceTimer!, forMode: "NSDefaultRunLoopMode")

    }

    @objc func displayOfflineTimerMessage(timer:NSTimer)
    {
        if let username:String = timer.userInfo as? String {
            offlineNotificationDebounceList.removeValueForKey(username)
            sendConnectionMessage(username, msg: username + " has left")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your selector takes a parameter so the name should be `displayOfflineTimerMessage:` (notice the : at the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the line as

```
debounceTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: debounceTimeInSeconds, target: self, selector: "displayOfflineTimerMessage:", userInfo: username, repeats: false)
```

Comment: made the change to add the ":" so now it sees the selector but now I get a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error on displyOfflineTimerMessage  when it calsl the sendConnectionMessage function.  Is there some sort of closure or variable that I need to capture?  The sendConnectionMessage makes a reference to self to update the message list in the view

Comment: ok found the issue with the exc_bad_instruction - it was unrelated to the question